# Generic VC++ vs g++ query

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, g++, header

I have trouble understanding the compilers.
The following code does work in UNIX under g++, but under VC++ it would not even compile. Anyone can provide valid reasons why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string tmp_nw_msg, crc_chksum, buffer;

    cout << "Enter the string : ";
    cin >> buffer;

    if (strlen(buffer.c_str()) >15 ) {
        tmp_nw_msg = buffer.substr(1,12);
        crc_chksum = buffer.substr(13,2);

        cout << " N/W msg : "<< tmp_nw_msg << endl;
        cout << " crc chksum : "<< crc_chksum << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

The following error is thrown by VC++, but in g++ it does work fine.

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '>>' : no
>   operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type
>   'std::string' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)    c:\documents
>   and settings\my
>   documents\visual studio
>   2005\projects\dummy_substr\dummy_substr\substr.cpp    13
>   Error 2   error C2679: binary '<<' : no
>   operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type
>   'std::string' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)    c:\documents
>   and settings\my
>   documents\visual studio
>   2005\projects\dummy_substr\dummy_substr\substr.cpp    19
>   Error 3   error C2679: binary '<<' : no
>   operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type
>   'std::string' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)    c:\documents
>   and settings\my
>   documents\visual studio
>   2005\projects\dummy_substr\dummy_substr\substr.cpp    20
>   Error 4   fatal error C1075: end of file
>   found before the left brace '{' at
>   'c:\documents and
>   settings\my documents\visual
>   studio
>   2005\projects\dummy_substr\dummy_substr\substr.cpp(9)'
>   was matched   c:\documents and
>   settings\my documents\visual
>   studio
>   2005\projects\dummy_substr\dummy_substr\substr.cpp    29

Output from g++ :

> Enter the string : BD2d1100mayor47E 
>   N/W msg : D2d1100mayor  crc chksum :
>   47

Comment: Which version of vc++ are you using?

Comment: Unrelated to the question per se, why are you using strlen(buffer.c_str()) rather than buffer.length()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to replace `#include <string.h>` by `#include <string>`

C++ headers don't have the `.h` extension to differentiate them from C headers that would have the same name.

Also, you don't need the `#include <stdio.h>` header for your program -- and in case you need to call stdio functions from a C++ program you should `#include <cstio>` anyway.

---

**EDIT: "If that really was the problem, the error should be on the definition of the string variables" commented by PierreBdR**

In MSVC++, `#include <iostream>` creates a cascade of includes which at some point `#include <stdexcept>`. Then when you look at the `stdexcept` header file, you can see `#include <xstring>`. MSVC++ definition and implementation of `std::string` really is in this `xstring` header which explains why the compiler knows the type even-though you didn't `#include <string>`.

Then if you look at the content of the `string` header, you can see this is where binary operators compatible with `std::string` are defined which explains why the error only pops up on the line containing `cin >> buffer;` statement.

Comment: If that really was the problem, the error should be on the definition of the string variables ... but I agree the OP should use standard headers?

Comment: This is weird, but it did work. Why or how?
I also checked for '#include <cstring>', but the compile failed.

Comment: `#include <cstring>` is the C++ way of including `string.h` which by any way doesn't define the `std::string` type.

Comment: I wish I could give +2 for the in-depth autopsy.